# How to keep pandas indexes when extracting columns

Tags: python, csv, pandas

So I have a file 500 columns by 600 rows and want to take the average of all columns for rows 200-400:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep= '\s+')
sliced_df=df.iloc[200:400]
```

Then create a new column of the averages of all rows across all columns.  And extract only that newly created column:

```
sliced_df['mean'] = sliced_df.mean(axis=1)
final_df = sliced_df['mean']
```

But how can I prevent the indexes from resetting when I extract the new column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think is not necessary create new column in `sliced_df`, only [`rename`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rename.html) name of `Series` and if need output as `DataFrame` add [`to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html). Indexes are not resetting, see sample bellow:

```
#random dataframe
np.random.seed(100)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(5,5)), columns=list('ABCDE'))
print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E
0  8  8  3  7  7
1  0  4  2  5  2
2  2  2  1  0  8
3  4  0  9  6  2
4  4  1  5  3  4

#in real data use df.iloc[200:400]
sliced_df=df.iloc[2:4]
print (sliced_df)
   A  B  C  D  E
2  2  2  1  0  8
3  4  0  9  6  2

final_ser = sliced_df.mean(axis=1).rename('mean')
print (final_ser)
2    2.6
3    4.2
Name: mean, dtype: float64

final_df = sliced_df.mean(axis=1).rename('mean').to_frame()
print (final_df)
   mean
2   2.6
3   4.2
```

Python counts from `0`, so maybe need change slice from `200:400` to `100:300`, see difference:

```
sliced_df=df.iloc[1:3]
print (sliced_df)
   A  B  C  D  E
1  0  4  2  5  2
2  2  2  1  0  8

final_ser = sliced_df.mean(axis=1).rename('mean')
print (final_ser)
1    2.6
2    2.6
Name: mean, dtype: float64

final_df = sliced_df.mean(axis=1).rename('mean').to_frame()
print (final_df)
   mean
1   2.6
2   2.6
```

Comment: This is the answer in my opinion.

Comment: @piRSquared - Thank you.

Comment: OMG... my wife would freak out.  It got as cold as -5 for about a week.  Now its around 0 to 10.

Answer (score 0):

Use copy() function as follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep= '\s+')
sliced_df=df.iloc[200:400].copy()
sliced_df['mean'] = sliced_df.mean(axis=1)
final_df = sliced_df['mean'].copy()
```